# Write temp installation.log to .install4j directory

Tags: install4j

During setup a temporary log file is written to directory %TEMP%. This file is moved as installation.log to ${installer:sys.installationDir}/.install4j after setup finished.

Is there a way to let install4j write this temp. log file always directly to directory .install4j? Having it there it would be much easier to find it in case the setup crashes.

We're still using install4j 5.0.11.

Thanks in advance!
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the installation may not exit at startup and the installation directory may be changed in the installer.

However, you can pass the VM parameter

```
-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=[path to log file]
```

to the installer to specify an alternative log file.

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks for the reply. I understand the problem, that the user may change the installation directory during installation. To write the log to .install4j as soon as it is defined by the user isn't possible (or too complicated)? regards! Frank

Comment: Unfortunately this is currently not supported.