# How to change installation.log file location when fresh installation?

Tags: install4j

How to change installation.log file location when fresh installation ?

I am tried with the below options on 'Installer' -> execution options -> Arguments

```
-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=${installer:sys.installationDir}/diaglogs/installation.log
```

but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write temp installation.log to .install4j directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192331/write-temp-installation-log-to-install4j-directory)

Answer (score 1):

> `-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=${installer:sys.installationDir}/diaglogs/installation.log`

That would not work, because the installation directory does not exist and is not even known at startup. You have to choose an absolute path for `-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile`, so this is only suitable for debugging purposes. As of 6.1.4 there is no option in install4j to change the location of the log file.

Comment: How installation.log created in .install4j directory after fresh installation ?

Comment: Yes, it is created there, but it's not configurable.

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.1.4 we added a "Copy file" action at the "Finish" screen and copied the logfile to a specified directory. For the file location you can use the installation variable `${installer:sys.logfile}`and for the destination something like `${installation:sys.installationDir}/dialogs/installation.log`. The only thing that is missing in the copied logfile is the last entry like "Installation successful" or something else. But this should be a workaround for your purpose until the logfile location is configurable in a further version.